# Pycurl WRITEDATA WRITEFUNCTION collision/crash

Tags: python, crash, libcurl, pycurl

How do I turnoff WRITEFUNCTION and WRITEDATA?

Using pycurl I have a class call curlUtil. In it I have pageAsString (self, URL) which returns a string.

To do this I setopt WRITEFUNCTION. Now in downloadFile (self, URL, fn, overwrite=0) I do an open and self.c.Setopt (pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, 0) which cause problems. Int is not a valid argument.

I then assumed WRITEDATA would overwrite the value or there would be a NOWRITEFUNCTION commend. NOWRITEFUNCTION didn't exist so I just used WRITEDATA and Python crashed.

I wrote a quick func called reboot() which closes curl, opens it again, and calls reset to put it in the default state. I call it in both pageAsString and downloadFile and there is no problem at all. But, I don't want to reinitialize curl. There might be some special options I set.

How do I turnoff WRITEFUNCTION and WRITEDATA?

Answer (score 2):

using the writefunction, instead of turning it off would save you a lot off trouble. you might want to rewrite your pageAsString by utilizing WRITEFUNCTION..

as an example:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
c = pycurl.Curl()
buffer = StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://example.com")
c.perform()
...
buffer.getvalue() # will return the data fetched.
```

Comment: My pageAsString works in a similar way.
The problem is when i open a file in do setpot(pycurl.WRITEDATA, file). However i could change it so it would use writedata but i wanted to know how to turn it off in casei need to turn off another option.

Comment: setting the writefunction to 0 will turn it off. you will have to take care of other things that libcurl will apply in that case. 
all are detailed here:  
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: i do this in my C version. In pycurl i get an error :(. It doesnt allow int's as a parameter. But its fine i can fix this by using writefunction instead of writedata